# outside domain network share for domain users

Tags: active-directory, domain

i don;t know if this is possible, i tried googling but didn't find any good leads where to start.

We have a windows server with a share location outside the domain, and we would like to give access to users using their active directory accounts. Would it be possible to query the ad server to confirm the user credentials without joining the server to the domain, if yes could you please point me in the right direction.

Thank you very much for your time

Comment: `Would it be possible to query the ad server to confirm the user credentials without joining the server to the domain?` - No.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just map the letter manually to those computer with a hardcoded username and password.

Is it a good practice ? no, as you have no control on the mapping after it's done. Like 5 years later when you change the server, you would need to redo all the mapping manually. It force to use a insecure configuration too, to not change the account password, if you want the mapping to last long.

Please see the [manual](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/gg651155(v=ws.11)) for the net use command;

```
net use [{<DeviceName> | *}] [\\<ComputerName>\<ShareName>[\<volume>]] [{**<Password>** | *}]] [**/user:[<DomainName>\]<UserName]**
>[/user:[<DottedDomainName>\]<UserName>] [/user: [<UserName@DottedDomainName>] [/savecred] [/smartcard] [{/delete | /persistent:{yes | no}}]
```